# Infix Expressions

Tags: c++, stl, stack, infix-notation

I am trying to evaluate an infix expression using two stacks, however, my program keeps getting a segmentation fault and I am not sure what is causing the error. I have tried following the pseudocode for the RPN algorithm, however I think my issue arises when I call doOperation. I am not sure what parameters to include when calling this. I know I need a (ValueType, char, ValueType), however I do not want to write doOperation (ch, ch, ch) since I am pretty sure that won't help. Can anyone help me figure out a way to call this function? (I'm pretty sure that's one of the reasons causing the segmentation fault).

Answer (score 0):

The `opStack` and `valStack` in `doOperation` should use the variable in `processExpression`.

Its function prototype should be like this:

```
ValueType doOperation(ValueType operandL, char operation, ValueType operandR, stack<char>& opStack, stack<ValueType>& valueStack)
```

Pay attention to the last two parameters: `stack<char>& opStack, stack<ValueType>& valueStack`.   They must be pointer-passed or reference-passed, NOT value-passed.

`processExpression` call `doOperation` like this: `doOperation(operandL, ch, operandR, opStack, valueStack)` .

Besides, the current segmentation fault happens because `opStack` and `valueStack` defined in `doOperation` has no items. `top()` will reference noexist value.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing these lines from `doOperation`:

```
stack<char> opStack;
stack<ValueType> valStack;

operandR = valStack.top();
valStack.pop();

operandL = valStack.top();
valStack.pop();

operation = opStack.top();
opStack.pop();
```

Note that your declaration of `double result` isn't there - you should keep that.

So, what's happening in the above lines:

- You create stacks `opStack` and `valStack`.  Both of these are empty.
- You call `.top()`, which does bad things when the stack is empty.  `.pop()` does bad things on empty stacks as well.
- You are attempting to assign values to the parameters you passed in.  Even if this was successful, your parameters would be useless.  You just end up creating/initializing them in your function any way.

Now, after removing the above lines, you'll need to change your calls to `doOperation`.  In `processExpression` you will want to do these calls *before* calling `doOperation`:

```
operandL = valStack.top();
valStack.pop();

operandR = valStack.top();
valStack.pop();

operation = opStack.top();
opStack.pop();

doOperation(operandL, operation, operandR)
```

Which isn't pretty, especially when you do that for the three times you call `doOperation`, but it's a start.  The first goal is to get working code.  You can make it pretty if you're so inclined later.

Also, and this is a bit pedantic, but you should rename your `operation` variable to be `operator`, since that is what it really is.  The "operation" is the thing that happens when you execute the operator.